# Steam is not working: SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred

Tags: steam

I have error when try to open steam:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Startup - updater built Jul 17 2019 06:13:47
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  46
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Checking for update on startup
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Checking for available updates...
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Download skipped by HTTP 304 Not Modified
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Nothing to do
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Verifying installation...
[2019-07-26 00:23:06] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2019-07-26 00:23:07] Verification complete
```

information of system:
**uname -a**

```
Linux home-PC 4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

The instructions on this page worked for me (Ubuntu 18.04, GTX 1650s): https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md

Nvidia:

To get the latest Nvidia drivers it is necessary to add the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Update to refresh packages:

`sudo apt update`

Warning: Please ensure your graphics card is supported by the 430 driver before installing. For a list of supported GPUs click here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us

Install the 440.82 driver:

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440 libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-gl-440:i386`

Install support for Vulkan API (will be functional only if you have a Vulkan capable GPU):

`sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386`

**Reboot to apply changes.**

Answer (score 0):

You might find this surprising, but this error is often just a side effect of a graphic driver update, resulting in the libraries and the kernel module being out of sync. The fix is to reboot the computer and start Steam again. Helped me more than once.